RichEdit. How can I find out exactly what changes were made in the text?
I would like to know the details about the changes made by the user in the RichEdit control.
How can I find out exactly what changes were made in the text, namely what was added or deleted, in which line? And is there any way at all to find out the details of the changes. Comparing the text before and after the EN_CHANGE message is not a reasonable solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
